# How to get rid of first column, i.e. row indices?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame written to CSV in the form:

```
,date,name,...
0,2014...,Peter,...
1,2014...,Julia,...
2,..
```

although I'm not adding this first column with the row indices anywhere. For removing the colum, this:

```
df.drop([df.columns[0]], axis = 0)
```

did not work. Can I get rid of this first column at all?

Comment: I believe the first column is the index of the dataframe, try writing with the `index=False` argument set. This is guessing you are using `DataFrame.to_csv()` for this.

Comment: You can just select without it: `df = df[df.columns[1:]]` but you're probably writing this to the csv when you cal `to_csv` as Anand has stated

Comment: thanks, that did the trick